# Showing a message box when username and password is incorrect

Tags: vb.net, winforms, passwords

I have a login form for my program and it works fine but when i input an username and password that is not in my database, the textbox for the username and password just clears the text and does not show the messagebox that says "incorrect username/password"

Here is my code:

```
 Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection( _
               "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= UserPass.mdb;")
    con.Open()
    Dim str As String
    str = "SELECT * FROM UserPass WHERE Username='" & txtUsername.Text & "' AND Password='" & txtPassword.Text & "'"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", txtUsername.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pass", txtPassword.Text)
    Dim sdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    ' It will be case sensitive if you compare usernames here.   
    If sdr.HasRows Then
        If sdr.Read Then
            If txtPassword.Text <> sdr("Password").ToString Or txtUsername.Text <> sdr("Username").ToString Then
                MessageBox.Show(" Incorrect Username/Password. Login Denied ", " Error! ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(" You are now Logged In! ", " Welcome! ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
                frmOne.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

How can i make my program show a messagebox when i input a username and password that is not in my database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Line sdr.HasRows doesn't look like it would fire.  On your select statement it won't have rows if username and password don't match.

Consider changing the code to this :

```
If sdr.HasRows Then
    If sdr.Read Then
            MessageBox.Show(" You are now Logged In! ", " Welcome! ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
            frmOne.Show()
            Me.Hide()
    End If
Else
    MessageBox.Show(" Incorrect Username/Password. Login Denied ", " Error! ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End If
```

Comment: your code works but it doesn't make the textboxes case sensitive anymore

Comment: @RaraArar Add your case checking logic back into the `If sdr.Read`

Comment: After i add the case checking logic back to the statements, the "sdr.HasRows" is automatically added

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you, it is using the method that DMudge showed you, but adding the case checking back. If it works Accept his answer.

```
If sdr.HasRows Then
    If sdr.Read Then
        If txtPassword.Text <> sdr("Password").ToString Or txtUsername.Text <> sdr("Username").ToString Then
            MessageBox.Show(" Incorrect Username/Password. Login Denied ", " Error! ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(" You are now Logged In! ", " Welcome! ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
            frmOne.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        End If
    End If
Else
    MessageBox.Show(" Incorrect Username/Password. Login Denied ", " Error! ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End If
```

Comment: @RaraArar You really should mark DMudge's answer as the correct one, I just used this answer to try to explain to you what I was saying in my Comment, Code is a lot easier to read this way.